# SP2013 & Responsive Design - How to do it right?

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries, sharepoint-2013

I'm a SP developer and also skilled in webdesign. My current task is to implement a responsive design along with a branding in a SP 2013 environment

Now I am in the situation to choose which one i would use to implement a responsive design in SP2013 and so I collected **pro's** and **con's** foreach technology.

What do you think ? Are there important aspects I'm missing ? Are there other solutions which are better suited for realizing this ? **Any input is welcome ! :)**

Comment: Getting SharePoint to be responsive.. now that's a task.. :|

Comment: It is, but VERY doable.

Comment: @JesseEarley I've only just seen your link, I'm ***very*** impressed you've managed to implement Bootstrap into SharePoint like you have, although that must of been a long-slog of developing templates and working within SharePoint designer(?) to get that to work, how about overriding all the ms classes and stylesheets? e.g. `.ms-promlink-root-2123412-12z`.. furthermore, how SharePoint2013 is contructed at the moment, with `#s4-workspace` being a 'hovered' `<div>` over everything.

Comment: at least if you can cut features. I created a simple mobileview with media queries simply by hiding everything but navigation and content, and then created a 1 column layout from the remaining content

Comment: @MackieeE Thanks! Since this was our first implementation of Bootstrap, it took us about 6 months, and that time period included EVERY design we have on the website (there are LOTS), and only 3 of us working on it (me, and 2 student designers of mine). We didn't use SharePoint designer, we only do deployments, so all markup work was done inside Visual Studio and deployed out to the server. Our CSS is housed on an internal CDN, so we could update that on the fly. You don't have to override all MS classes and stylesheets, in fact, we don't override many at all.

Answer (score 2):

### Device Channels

Yes I'm talking about `Device Channels` even when they are not mentioned in the question, because they can deliver the best performance and optimizability for the enduser and the client - in my opinion :)

**Pro**

- individual designed `HTML/CSS` and `JS` foreach device
- -- no need for hiding or removing incompatible elements
- -- faster because you just load things you really need
- -- faster because you will likely have less `CSS/JS and HTML`
- -- faster because you can use optimized code foreach device
- -- better you can better point out which channel has errors and changes dont affect the other channels

**Con**

- individual designed `HTML/CSS` and `JS` foreach device
- -- you have to append changes to each masterpage
- -- more work to accomplish the same result (in general)
- -- redundancy
- bound to `User Agent Strings`
- growing diversity of devices
- -- may equals growing diversity of masterpages >> work

[These are not all but my main points. Klick here to start your own research.](https://www.google.de/search?q=sharepoint%20device%20channels%20contra&oq=sharepoint%20device%20channels%20contra&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l2.6268j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=sharepoint%202013%20device%20channels%20vs%20responsive%20design)

---

### Bootstrap

**Pro**

- mighty, easy to use framework
- -- a lot of documentation
- -- fast results
- -- if you like it - all the Bootstrap styles
- there are already projects using it so you may dont have to build it from scratch
- -- http://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/

**Con**

- Bootstrap is a huge framework and has 8000+ lines of code in the unminified `CSS` and `JS` files
- -- 2 requests extra for ~ 130kb & 30kb
- -- a lot of styles and script for your browser to handle
- Bootstrap is not build for use in SharePoint
- -- it's overwriting SharePoint styles which makes some features (`ComposedLooks` for ex.) less valuable
- -- there are a lot of custom `CSS` needed to make it work seamless with SharePoint
- SharePoint has it's own weird way to do things and that interferes with BootStrap
- -- tons of `CSS`
- -- tons of `JS`
- -- tons of `HTML Attributes`

[These are not all but my main points. Klick here to start your own research.](https://www.google.de/search?q=bootstrap%20downsides&oq=bootstrap%20downsi&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2.6285j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

---

### Media Queries

**Pro**

- only necessary `CSS`
- no `JS` if you dont wan't to
- you can create your own layout
- with `response.js` even in IE6 working
- you can easily separate which features should be available in certain screen sizes

**Con**

- several sets of `CSS` depending on the number of `Breakpoints`
- every feature needs to be developed by yourself
- it's not easy to write generic code that can process every SP2013 Page
- -- it depends on the complexity of the content shown. I write about 150 lines of `CSS` that created a mobile view for publishing pages that contained the navigation and content, but no features like editing, etc.
- -- if the client's want every feature on his smartphone, there is a hell lot of work and testing needed. (Plus who the hell wants to do that on their phone?)

---

### Conclusion

I'm not sure yet (and it would be awesome to get a lot of feedback to my results), but i tend to use `Media Queries`. Why ? Well SharePoint has it's own way to handle desktop users and i wouldn't customize that build in functionality if not explicit ordered. On the other hand SharePoint doesn't provide a real UI for smartphones. I don't want to use BootStrap because it contains a lot of styling which will produce problems in branded environments. And I won't use `Device Channels` because of the downsides.

Answer (score 0):

Use Botostrap. I work at a University (http://www.cmich.edu) and our entire website (internal and external) is built in SharePoint 2013 using this Framework, and I was the lead on its implementation. If you haven't used Bootstrap at all, it takes a little getting used to, especially in the SharePoint environment, but as far as I'm concerned, responsive design is the only way to go that's going to produce the best results. Check our University site out, if you have questions, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your response !
A bad thing about BootStrap is, that it requires heavy html modification. A Microsoft colleague who is working at the same project, demanded that the .master modifications should be as minimalistic as possible. I could do it with SASS, but it would be a pain to extend hundreds of classes :-/

Comment: Actually, it doesn't require as much HTML modification as you might think. Really all you need is the Bootstrap wrapper classes (container, row, col, and navigation wrappers), and that's pretty much it. SharePoint markup will just get folded inside those wrappers and Bootstrap will take care of the rest.

Comment: That depends on the usecase - I am not creating a website for the www but a publishing intranet with several custom webparts and pagelayouts. I've done my own POC and tried the a solution from Eric Overfield (http://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/) but it seems like it would need a lot further modification.

Comment: Our implementation is this: 1 Custom Master Page with Many Custom Page Layouts. Both the Master Page and Page Layouts would need to have modified markup, yes, and if you have custom web parts and want those to be responsive, their markup may need to be changed as well (though not always the case, as a lot of out-of-the-box web parts don't require any modification to be responsive, as long as their container is responsive).